# C# How to access inherited object from parent List

Tags: c#, list, object, parent, inherited

I'm trying to find a way to make a list of parent object with a variety of inherited objects. Here is an example.

```
class Prog {
    public Prog ( ) {
        List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
        shapes.Add( new Cube() );
        shapes.Add( new Shape() );

        //All those ways will not work, I cannot figure a way how to do this
        shapes[0].CubeFunction(); 
        (Cube)shapes[0].CubeFunction();
        Cube cube = shapes[0];
    }
}

class Shape {
    public Shape (){}
}

class Cube : Shape {        
    public Cube (){}
    public void CubeFunction(){}
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the code in class Prog to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your cast version is nearly right - it's only wrong because of precedence. You'd need:

```
((Cube)shapes[0]).CubeFunction();
```

Alternatively:

```
Cube cube = (Cube) shapes[0];
cube.CubeFunction();
```

The need to cast like this is generally a bit of a design smell, mind you - if you can avoid it, it's worth trying to do so.

Comment: Why is it a design smell? How could the compiler know what is the type? I hope Eric didn't read your smell comment... `:)`

Comment: Thank you very much for this very fast answer :)

Comment: @gdoron: It's usually a design smell to *need* to do this. I'm not saying that the requirement to cast in this situation is the smell - I'm saying that the situation itself (having to treat one element of a collection in a different way) is a smell.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not sure the cast is valid and don't want an [InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to be thrown, you can do like this:

```
Cube cube = shapes[0] as Cube;
if (cube == null)
{
    // cast is not valid
}
else
{
    cube.CubeFunction();
}
```